# Which .css theme file changes the buttons on top of nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, themes, gtk, gtk3, css

This is what I am talking about:

[image: pic]

I'm making a theme and I don't know what I should be looking for, but I think it is somewhere in the gtk.css file.

Edit: I know its in the gtk-widgets.css file, but can someone point to where?